# Table Styled Input for Screen Readers

Tags: html, wcag2.0

Take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLJKW.jpg). 
I have a table containing input. Each input is defined by a column header cell and a row header cell. How would you ensure that blind users know what to type in each input field?

Let us use this following simplified html table as example:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Income</th>
    <th>Change</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Personal income</th>
    <td><input type="number" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Company earnings</th>
    <td><input type="number" value="0"></td>
    <td><input type="number" value="0"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzr6rmzx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is described by W3 in example 3:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/grouping/

Basically you need to use fieldset, legends and labels that are hidden. The example uses a class that hides labels but i suggest you instead consider aria-label tag which are only read by screen readers (and other assistive technologies) but are visually hidden.