# Accessibility issue with HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

I have below a sample structure of an HTML table and I'm looking for an output for the   NVDA screen reader as below.

```
Name            INDIA   Switzerland   Germany

Country Name      ☑        ☑           ☑
```

Looking for output for NVDA Screen reader
If I select checbox1
Then output
Country Name , INDIA, Checbox1 is checked

If I select checbox2
Then output
Country Name,  Switzerland, Checbox2 is checked

If I select checbox3
Then output
Country Name,  Germany, Checbox3 is checked

Here is table structure

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
        INDIA
    </th>
    <th>
        Switzerland
    </th>

    <th>
        Germany
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country Name</td>
    <td>Checkbox1</td>
    <td>> Checkbox2</td>
    <td>> Checkbox3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table Styled Input for Screen Readers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408353/table-styled-input-for-screen-readers)

Comment: Wrapping your headers in `<thead>` and the table data in `<tbody>` should do the trick for NVDA.

Comment: Actually, is your table data including more rows? If not, I’d assume that your table only has presentational purpose, and you should use `<fieldset>` and `<label>` elements, and CSS to arrange them in a grid.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem necessary that the screen reader says "Country name" before "Switzerland", "Germany"  or "India" every time, as they are obviously country names.
Repeating "Country name" all the time is going to become annoying at the end, as it doesn't really bring any useful information. It's enough if it is said just once.

I suggest something like the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Country name</th>
    <th scope="col" id="switzerland">Switzerland</th>
    <th hscope="col" id="germany">Germany</th>
    <th scope="col" id="india">India</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="switzerland" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="germany" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="india" /></td>
  </tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

Notice the following:

- The "country name" header cell is scope=row, meaning that "Country name" will normally be said only once, when landing on the row for the first time
- "Switzerland", "Germany" and "India" header celles are scope=col, meaning that they will be announced when landing on the corresponding column
- This is absolutely not a problem to have a th with scope=row in the same row as several th with scope=col, as it isn't a problem conversely either
- Attribute aria-labelledby is set on the checkboxes in order to be sure that they are announced when reaching the checkboxes with tab. They shouldn't be necessary, as the screen reader is smart enough to already announce the header celll while changing column, but just in doubt, it's probably better to have them so we are sure that the checkboxes have an explicit accessible label. There is a small risk to get "Switzerland", "Germany" and "India" announced twice every time, but since it's short, it isn't so dramatic
- It's perfectly possible to reference several IDs in aria-labelledby and for example make "Country name" be announced each time, but note again how I didn't do it  because, as already said, "Country name" repeated all the time doesn't bring any useful information

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the "country name" cell as a `th` and apply the `scope` attribute to all `th`, using `row` and `col` as values, thereby indicating to what cells the different `th` headers apply:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">
        INDIA
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        Switzerland
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
        Germany
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Country Name</th>
    <td>Checkbox1</td>
    <td>Checkbox2</td>
    <td>Checkbox3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

Comment: If I select checbox1 Then output Country Name , INDIA, Checbox1 is checked  this step is working fine but for the second step output is not as expected 

 If I select checbox2 Then output  is coming  as below :                                                               Switzerland, Checbox2 is checked                                                                                                                    expected output is : Country Name, Switzerland, Checbox2 is checked

Answer (score 0):

An HTML checkbox input has a `label` attribute with a `for` attribute that corresponds to the `id` of the actual checkbox. Use JavaScript to get the value of `id` of the checkbox input, which can tell you the country name.

See [Checkbox Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)